# Expression to query whether date is within last month?

Tags: t-sql

I'm struggling to think up the easiest way to get all rows/records that were create within the last month. I can build a sortof convoluted one below but is there a simplier way?

```
SELECT
    * 
FROM
    MyTable
WHERE
    MONTH( createdAt ) >= MONTH( GET_DATE() ) - 1
    AND
    YEAR( createdAt ) = YEAR( GET_DATE );
```

The above would work but not for December records. Any advice how to simplify this and handle December created records?

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @startOfMonth date = DATEFROMPARTS( YEAR( SYSUTCDATETIME() ), MONTH( SYSUTCDATETIME() ), 1 )

SELECT
    *
FROM
    myTable
WHERE
    createdAt >= @startOfMonth
```

Or inline it (SQL Server should detect the RHS is constant so using a variable won't increase performance):

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    myTable
WHERE
    createdAt >= DATEFROMPARTS( YEAR( SYSUTCDATETIME() ), MONTH( SYSUTCDATETIME() ), 1 )
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for records WITHIN the last month I am assuming you mean the last 30 days this will work:

```
SELECT * 
FROM myTable
where createdAt >= CAST(DATEADD(day,-30,GETDATE()) as date)
```

If you are actually looking for records that were in last month then this will work:

```
SELECT *
from myTable
WHERE createdAt >= CAST( DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, -1, GETDATE()) - 2, 0) as date)
```